# Keeping Hibernate Session from Expiring via Annotations? -- failed to lazily initialize a collection of role

Tags: hibernate, spring, exception, lazy-evaluation, transactional

I have a hibernate DAO that is throwing a "failed to lazily initialize a collection of role" Exception when trying to access a member of the returned object that is a bag/Collection.

I understand the scope of the problem throwing the exception.  Hibernate returns my object, and for any Collections, returns proxy objects.  In my caller, when I go to access those proxy objects, **because the hibernate session has expired**, this exception is thrown.

What I want to know is, how can I keep the session from expiring **using annotations**?  Is it possible?

For instance if my calling method is:

```
@RequestMapping("refresh.url")
public ModelAndView refresh(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, int id) throws Exception {
    TestObject myObj = testObjDao.get(id);
    // throws the exception
    myObj.getCollection();
```

How would I prevent this exception using annotations?  I know one solution would be to extend the hibernate session via a callback which in pseudocode might look something like:

```
@RequestMapping("refresh.url")
public ModelAndView refresh(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, int id) throws Exception {
    session = get hibernate session...
    session.doInSession(new SessionCallback() {
        TestObject myObj = testObjDao.get(id);
        // no longer throws the exception
        myObj.getCollection();
    });
```

but this seems rather repetitive to have in all of my functions that need to access collections.  isn't there a way to simply slap an @Transactional annotation on there and be done with it?  as in:

```
@RequestMapping("refresh.url")
@Transactional  // this doesn't extend the session to this method?
public ModelAndView refresh(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, int id) throws Exception {
    TestObject myObj = testObjDao.get(id);
    // throws the exception
    myObj.getCollection();
```

thanks for your help in explaining this to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I used was to use the @LazyCollection annotation on the collection in the DAO.

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "<something here>", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.FALSE)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to do the following:

1) Let Spring manage your transaction:

You can read more about it here:
http://www.mkyong.com/spring/spring-aop-transaction-management-in-hibernate/

and here:

http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html#transaction-declarative

2) Now the lazy loading:

When you fetch object from Hibernate all its lazy associations are returned as proxy and then when you access proxy classes you get the exception because your Hibernate session is closed.

The solution is to use open Session in View Filter/Interceptor.

http://www.paulcodding.com/blog/2008/01/21/using-the-opensessioninviewinterceptor-for-spring-hibernate3/

it will look exactly like this:

```
<mvc:interceptors>
<bean class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.support.OpenSessionInViewInterceptor">
<property name="sessionFactory">
<ref local="sessionFactory"/>
</property>
</bean>
</mvc:interceptors>
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Hibernate sessions are different from web sessions and they don't expire. They get closed either manually by your code or by the infrastructure (Spring for example).

In your case is not clear how your session gets created on the first place, since if you enter DAO without a session you would get completely different exception (`No Session Bound to Thread`). So, somehow your session gets created and closed. My wild guess is that your DAO is made transactional either via `@Transactional` or via interceptors so session is initiated when you enter it and closed when you exit DAO method. In this case, putting `@Transactional` on your MVC method will work for as long as transaction propagation on DAO is set to `PROPAGATION_REQUIRED`.

Keep in mind, though, that you can't carry your collection outside of method annotated via `@Transactional`. For example you should not put it in http session. If that's a requirement, you may want to consider special DTO objects to copy data.